# Xcode build issue couldn't to find auto-linked framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build-settings, xcode-build-settings

I've been struggling with this issue for days now :( When building my iOS app in the simulator it works fine (debug build), but as soon as I'm trying to build to my iPhone 11 (v 14.5.1) my build fails with these errors:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'GoogleDataTransport'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Protobuf'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FirebaseInstallations'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'GoogleToolboxForMac'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

I'm using Xcode 12.5. I've tried various suggestions like:

- Adding `LD_VERIFY_BITCODE` to `User-Defined` in `Build Settings` with
  the value of `NO`
- `Enable Bitcode` in `Build Settings` with the value of `NO`
- Deleting derived data
- Uninstalling and installing Pods
- Clean build
- Make sure that `Framework Search Paths` looks correct. I only have
  `$(inherited)`
- Changing `$(inherited)` to `recursive`
- Made sure I have the .xcworkspace file open and not the .xcodeproj

Any other possible solutions out there?

Comment: Are you using an Apple Silicon mac?

Comment: Nope -  I'm on OSX 11.2.3 (Big Sur) on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)

Comment: Did you do `Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > NO` for all targets (including your app targets & multiple PODS targets)?

Comment: All targets in Pods do have `Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > YES`, but that's a lot of pod targets. Should the all have `NO` ? If so how do I ensure that newly added Pods will have `NO` as well?

Comment: It's worth a shot.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help unfortunately :/

Comment: It seems like I've god rid of the auto-linking errors, bu upgrading alle firebase packages to latest version. Its failing now with `symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

Comment: Did you delete `Derived Data` & `Clean Build Folder` after `pod update`?

Comment: yes, force close xcode, pod update, delete derived data, clean build

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to `Flipper` if I comment out `use_flipper!()` in the `Podfile` it works. Unfortunately I haven't figured out a good way to disable flipper when running on local device only.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting `ENABLE_BITCODE = NO` for all of your targets (including your app targets & multiple PODS targets).

Here's what you can add at the end of Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ENABLE_BITCODE"] = "NO"
    end
  end
end
```

Save it and do a `pod install`.
Do a clean build, see if it helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help unfortunately :/